# Spring security 3.2 - CSS display issue

Tags: java, css, spring, primefaces

I am trying to include 'Spring security 3.2.0' into my existing web application which is built without spring and using Primefaces & EJB 3.

When I started with the basic configuration, and tried access the page displays without CSS styles. The below logs have some information about the path. I am not sure what I am missing.

Many thanks in advance.

**Application Logs:-**

```
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 INFO  DispatcherServlet:472 - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 831 ms
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:141 - Servlet 'spring' configured successfully
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/myapp/resources/css/myapp.css]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/myapp/resources/images/bg_myapp_header.gif]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/myapp/resources/js/myapp.js]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/myapp/resources/images/2_arial_white_myapp_bg.png]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/myapp/resources/images/logo.png]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:209 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/css/myapp.css
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:209 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/js/myapp.js
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:219 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/js/myapp.js]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:209 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/images/bg_myapp_header.gif
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:209 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/images/2_arial_white_myapp_bg.png
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:209 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/images/eba_logo.png
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:219 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/images/2_arial_white_myapp_bg.png]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:219 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/images/bg_myapp_header.gif]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:219 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/css/myapp.css]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 WARN  PageNotFound:1108 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/resources/images/bg_myapp_header.gif] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 WARN  PageNotFound:1108 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/resources/images/2_arial_white_myapp_bg.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 WARN  PageNotFound:1108 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/resources/js/myapp.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:219 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/images/logo.png]
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:300 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:300 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:300 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 WARN  PageNotFound:1108 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/resources/css/myapp.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:946 - Successfully completed request
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:946 - Successfully completed request
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:946 - Successfully completed request
            05-02-2014 16:05:58 WARN  PageNotFound:1108 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/resources/images/logo.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
            <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">


                <authentication-manager>
                    <authentication-provider>
                        <user-service>
                            <user name="jay" password="jay" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                        </user-service>
                    </authentication-provider>
                </authentication-manager>

                <http pattern="/resources/css/**" security="none" />
                <http pattern="/resources/images/**" security="none" />
                <http pattern="/resources/js/**" security="none" />

                <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

                    <intercept-url pattern="/faces/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll" />

                    <intercept-url pattern="/faces/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />
                    <intercept-url pattern="/faces/search.xhtml" access="permitAll" />

                    <intercept-url pattern="/faces/create.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
                    <intercept-url pattern="/faces/update.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />


                    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
                </http>
            </beans:beans>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

                <mvc:annotation-driven />

                <import resource="spring-security.xml" />

                <mvc:resources location="/css/**" mapping="/resources/css/" />
                <mvc:resources location="/images/**" mapping="/resources/images/" />
                <mvc:resources location="/js/**" mapping="/resources/js/" />

            </beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


                <!-- JSF configuration -->
                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                </servlet>
                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>

                <!-- Filter for not to have local cache, instead load from server -->
                <filter>
                    <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
                    <filter-class>com.jai.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
                </filter>

                <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
                </filter-mapping>

                <listener>
                    <listener-class>com.jai.HttpSessionChecker</listener-class>
                </listener>

                <!-- Primefaces theme -->
                <context-param>
                    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
                    <param-value>aristo</param-value>
                </context-param>


                <!-- Spring security configuration  -->
                <context-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
                </context-param>

                <filter>
                    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
                </filter>

                <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                </filter-mapping>

                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                </servlet>
                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>

                <listener>
                    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
                </listener>

            </web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

what if you remove **resource** in path

```
<security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. But its still the same even if I remove the /resources/

Comment: Yes spring security works fine.  <http auto-config="true" /> gives me the user/password dialog as expected. Once I fix the CSS style issue I would do further steps on security.

Comment: Continuing with the problem? You can try adding `<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />` in `spring-servlet.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , solved it by removing  ** mark in (location="/css/**") and it worked for me ,define a folder to save your resource withing Web-content folder.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/assets/"/>`
```

Folder structure
application_name-->WebContent-->assets-->css

JSP CSS URL

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrapStyles.css"/>"></link>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.12.0.js" />"></script>
```